# my tailwind CSS is no working after deploying site on netlify while it's working ok locally

Tags: debugging, tailwind-css, netlify

this is the URL of my website: https://devartverse.netlify.app/

please help me out to solve this issue.

MZT!

I tried to resolve it by my own but I don't reached the solution.

```
and this is my tailwind.config.js file's code:

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["*"],
  theme: {
    
    extend: {
      fontFamily:{
      
        'montserrat':['montserrat'],
        'gilroy':['gilroy'],
        'gilroy-bold':['gilroy-bold'],
        'poppins':['poppins']
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Are you using PostCSS to generate the final styles? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss

The final output should contain the actual css but I can see `@tailwind base;` etc in your css file: https://devartverse.netlify.app/style.css

Comment: yeah yeah i added it before so i have to remove it from my CSS file?? and yes i have deleted all the files and directories of node and tailwind and now I'm working with play CDN link of tailwind but it shows error in console and now i decided to follow cli method to import tailwind CSS in my project.. and yes I'll be very happy if you guide me further if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: With Tailwind there is the build step to create the final CSS output. You can build the complete site into a folder and deploy to Netlify, or configure Netlify to handle the build step. Can you clarify how you are deploying to Netlify?